# Error when editing product - source model not found

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, model

Whenever I try to **edit** a **product** i get a printing exception error.

Only one module has been installed recently but even when that is disabled the error is still there?

I changed the `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml` and tried again and it says this:

> Source model `estimateddelivery/attribute_source_enable` not found for attribute `estimated_delivery_enable`.

```
Trace:
#0 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "e...')
#1 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /home/stovespa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(250): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->editAction()
#17 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#18 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/XXXXXX/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error normally occurs if an attribute has been added from an extension **AND** the extension was uninstalled later. *(assigned `source_model` is not present anymore)*

Please delete `estimated_delivery_enable` attribute from **Admin - Catalog - Manage Attributes**.

**Edit:** try the *"hard way"* ... run this from your root folder

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');

$setup = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'estimated_delivery_enable');
$setup->endSetup();
```

Comment: Hello,  Thank you for the super fast response, I couldnt see a way of deleting that attritube only edit.  the only module that has been removed recently was AWworks blog as ive installed Amasty blog pro instead?

Comment: Is there no button `Delete Attribute` in manage attributes section? Edit: this is no core attribute ... and source models are normally set from extension (can't do this from backend).

Comment: No unfortunately it only says, Reset, Save Attribute, Save and Continue Edit

Comment: This module hasnt been used for about 6 months so not sure why its causing issues now

Comment: Updated answer, please test on development server before ... this will finally delete this product attribute.

Comment: When you say run from root what does that mean? sorry :(

Comment: Add a file with this content to your magento installation and exexute it from your browser ... `http://yourdomain/filename.php`

Comment: removed attribute but didnt fix the problem unfortunately

Comment: Mhhh, i use this code for serveral uninstall scripts ... and it should work ... Please check if the attribute is still available in "Mange Attributes" section. You may also clear cache.

Comment: It has successfully removed the attribute but I still cant edit products, ill check error code and edit original post in case its fresh error :)